# Is it possible to query tags and their values using AWS CDK Aspects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cdk

I'm pretty new to using CDK Aspects, but I've been trying for a few days now, and I cannot seem to find a way to read the tags that are attached to a resource (more specifically, an ec2 instance)

I would like to essentially implement a "cdk-nag"-type check to verify that specific tags with valid values exist during the synth, and throw an error if they don't.

I can see that the tags exist in the cfn template that is produced from the synth, but when the `visit` method is executed, I try to query the tags and they always return None.  I've tried to resolve the token that is returned, and I've tried using the methods and properties available when I access the `cfnInstance.tags` property, but the returned `TagManager` object never seems to contain anything in, say, `rendered_tags`, `render_tags()`, `has_tags()`.

Am I missing something obvious?  Again, I'm new to using Aspects, but I don't often have this kind of issue that is just completely eluding me.

Code excerpt:

```py
    @jsii.implements(cdk.IAspect)
    class TagValidation:
        def visit(self, node):
            print(f'NODE TYPE IS:  {type(node)}')

            if isinstance(node, ec2.Instance):
                print('ec2.Instance TRIGGERED')
            if isinstance(node, ec2.CfnInstance):
                print('ec2.CfnInstance TRIGGERED')
                print(f'TAGS ARE: {node.tags}')
                print(f'TAGS ARE: {node.tags.rendered_tags}')
                print(f'TAGS ARE: {node.tags.tag_values().keys()}')
                tags = cdk.CfnResource(node,
                    'tagsofresource',
                    type='AWS::EC2::Instance',
                    properties={ "Tags": node.tags.tag_values() }
                    )
                print(f'TAGS:  {tags["Name"]}')
```

Returns:

```
bash-5.0$ cdk synth
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'cdk_ce_aspects.cdk_ce_aspects_stack.CdkCeAspectsStack'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class '...custom class...'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class '...custom class...'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'jsii._reference_map.InterfaceDynamicProxy'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.aws_ec2.CfnSecurityGroup'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.CfnResource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'jsii._reference_map.InterfaceDynamicProxy'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Instance'>
ec2.Instance TRIGGERED
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.aws_iam.CfnInstanceProfile'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.CfnMapping'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.aws_ec2.CfnInstance'>
ec2.CfnInstance TRIGGERED
TAGS ARE: <aws_cdk.TagManager object at 0x7fe67cafbd50>
TAGS ARE: <jsii._reference_map.InterfaceDynamicProxy object at 0x7fe67cafb650>
TAGS ARE: dict_keys([])
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.CfnResource'>
NODE TYPE IS:  <class 'aws_cdk.CfnResource'>
```

Thank you in advance.

Using latest CDK 2.30.x , Python 3.7 and 3.9

Comment: Did you solve that maybe ?

Comment: @Maciej, unfortunately not yet.  Still hoping for an answer.

Comment: Try github issues / feature request for CDK maybe :)